# call_user_func replacing class file name with random string

Tags: php, namespaces

I am having an weird issue when calling call_user_func. The name of the class I am passing, somehow gets its name replaced by a random string. The funny thing is that it all works fine on my local deployment, and then it breaks when I move it live (both local and live are running PHP5.3)

call_user_func() tries to call a function from another controller class, and returns an error as the name of the class is replaced with a random string.

**UPDATED**

The call looks like this:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
  public function actionView()
  {
    $this->resource_class = 'site\frontend\controllers\api\v1'.'\\'.ucfirst($_GET['resource']).'Controller';
    if(class_exists($this->resource_class))
       call_user_func(array($this->resource_class, 'view'), $_GET);
  }
}
```

At this stage, $this->resource_class is:

```
site\frontend\controllers\api\v1\OffersController
```

The target class (site/frontend/controllers/api/v1/OffersController.php) looks like this:

```
namespace site\frontend\controllers\api\v1;
class OffersController extends \ApiController
{
  public function view($params)
  { 
     // code...
  }
}
```

and the error I get is this one:

```
include(/home/username/public_html/site/frontend/controllers/api/v1/evm9pfgpg9u0k9pk.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So for some bizarre reason, **OffersController** is being scrambled into **evm9pfgpg9u0k9pk**

OffersController class exists inside site\frontend\controllers\api\v1 namespace, and a public view() method is available in there. As I mentioned, it does work on my local deployment.

Has anyone seen that before and have any idea of what could be causing it?
Thanks for your help! :)

Has anyone had this before?

Comment: Your issue is not with `call_user_func` but about how you can (or can not) debug your auto-loader. Which extact classname is requested for autoloading?

Comment: Maybe this class of yours have a __toString() function that returns the offers number?  (just a thought)

Comment: Thanks for replying. hakre, the class is called OffersController. It's namespace is site\frontend\controllers\api\v1. So the variable containing the class name is site\frontend\controllers\api\v1\OffersController.

roychri, I believe that's not the case but I will have a look at it anyway!

Comment: @guivalerio: You should add the code to your question where the error appears. I mean something is running that include, isn't it?

Comment: @hakre, I have updated the question with more of the code. Hope it helps. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @guivalerio: I added an answer below (which does not answer it) but hopefully I can make more clear what the point is.

Answer (score 0):

> So for some bizarre reason, `OffersController` is being scrambled into `evm9pfgpg9u0k9pk`

That is not *precise*. In fact the **classname** `OffersController` is mapped to the **filename**:

```
/ ... /public_html/site/frontend/controllers/api/v1/evm9pfgpg9u0k9pk.php
```

Filename and classname are often related but are two different things. If you want to find out why the classname is mapped to that filename, you need to share the source-code of your autoloader as well. The call of [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists) will trigger your auto-loader if the class does not exists yet.

Further it's that [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) is not related to the error you get, because you call `class_exists` in front of it.

Comment: thanks again. I am using Yii Framework, so the autoloader us the framework's one. I had a look at the error returned again and the problem is that call_user_func() has the correct class name, but is sending the random string to spl_autoload_call(): `spl_autoload_call("site\frontend\controllers\api\v1\evm9pfgpg9u0k9pk")`

Comment: Wow, just changed the way I called the method with call_user_func and it worked! no idea why though. `call_user_func(array($this->resource_class, 'view'), $_GET);` was causing me that weird issue, so I tried changing it to `call_user_func($this->resource_class.'::view', $_GET);` instead and it just worked! the class name is not replaced anymore with random crap. really weird...

Comment: Just seeing your classname is `"site\frontend\controllers\api\v1\OffersController"` which you might want to prefix with a `"\"` if that is your namespace. The change you made is changing it into a static function call, don't know if that is what you want. If yes, declare the `view` function as `static`. But sounds esoteric what you experience ;)

Comment: I have prefixed it but that didn't change the so called esoteric behaviour :P Although I call it as a static method, the function in the Offers controller if public and it works fine. Hope one day I understand what the heck was going on there! Thanks for your help.